# Spring MVC: components for user registration?

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, security, registration, user-management

I'm creating my first Spring MVC app on Tomcat 6.  Certain pages will be browseable by all and other pages will be restricted to registered users.  I'm looking for advice on how best to configure app security to support this.  Coming from ASP.NET, which provides [Login Controls that provide registration/login/password recovery/et](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx)c components, I'm wondering whether Spring MVC has equivalent functionality.  Since this is common functionality, I'm hoping there are some reusable components that I can leverage so that I don't have to write all of this from scratch.

This is basically a small toy app so I don't need super-duper security.  I'm looking for components that will make writing web user authentication/authorization easier (or how to leverage built-in Tomcat capabilities).  I'm fairly new to Java web development so any suggestions on how to quickly build this functionality would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security doesn't have all those features, but you can easily build those features using Spring Security. Spring Security takes care of authentication and ACL features.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/

Comment: I was hoping to avoid building most of it.  I'm surprised that basic web user management components are not included as part of some java web app framework.

Comment: @Sajee, I just came across your question looking for the same thing. Did you happen to come across another, out-of-the box solution?

Comment: @biggvsdiccvs No, I gave up shortly after I posted the question.  Since it's been nearly 6 years since I asked, I'm hoping there's a solution by now. :-)

Comment: @Sajee I looked briefly and haven't found such a solution. I'm more familiar with Tomcat, but am considering using asp.net (thanks to  your post) for a simple website whose most complicated part will be the user registration. It will run on Linux and it's not entirely clear whether this component would be compatible; if you have any comments about that, I would love to hear them.